# How to get values from an xml using Csharp - Linq to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have an xml with the following structure:

```
<cadastro>
<nome>Jose da Silva</nome>
<endereco>Rua Sete de Setembro</endereco>
<cidade>Porto Alegre</cidade>
</cadastro>
```

I need to get this information and insert, respectively, into three textbox.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-an-element-with-a-specific-attribute).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and amend the question appropriately: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask